# Bloquear al navegador IE en mi web

Tags: apache, internet-explorer

Intento bloquear toda conexión que se produzca desde IE(daigual la versión).
Ejecuto este código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE [NC] RewriteRule ^[^denied.html](.*)$ http://adnsuite.com/denied.html [L] </IfModule>
```

Pero nada, puedo acceder tranquilamente con IE

Comment: Te refieres a que tu web no sea visitada desde IE o que si abres IE no tenga conexion a nada?

Comment: lo primero que comentas, no quiero que nadie si usa un navegador IE pueda acceder,y si es el caso pues se usará una redireccion.

Comment: Yo no tengo ni idea , pero he encontrado varios enlaces que espero que te puedan ayudar [link1](http://www.devin.com/ieblock_howto.shtml) y [link2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/blocking-browsers-based-on-http_user_agent-in-apache-server-%40-centos-4175610567/)

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Ahora se utiliza Trident en vez de MSIE, por eso no te funcionaba tu solución:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.useful.php

Te facilito la solución en PHP, aunque te serviría cualquier de las del enlace:

```
<?php
    foreach([
        'MSIE',
        'Trident',
    ] as $ie) if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$ie))
        die('Página no accesible para IE');
?>
<div>Contenido visible fuera de IE</div>
```